# How do I add an element to the value of a hash map that pairs strings with vectors of strings?

Tags: vector, hashmap, rust

Like many new Rustaceans, I've been working my way through the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/). I'm reading through the chapter on collections, and I'm stuck on [one of the exercises](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html). It reads:

> Using a hash map and vectors, create a text interface to allow a user to add employee names to a department in a company. For example, “Add Sally to Engineering” or “Add Amir to Sales.” Then let the user retrieve a list of all people in a department or all people in the company by department, sorted alphabetically.

Here is my code so far:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::OccupiedEntry;
use std::collections::hash_map::VacantEntry;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome to the employee database text interface.\nHow can I help you?");

    let mut command = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut command)
        .expect("Failed to read line.");

    command = command.to_lowercase();

    let commands = command.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();

    let mut department = commands[3];
    let mut name = commands[1];

    let mut employees = HashMap::new();

    if commands[0] == "add" {
        match employees.entry(department) {
            VacantEntry(entry) => entry.entry(department).or_insert(vec![name]),
            OccupiedEntry(entry) => entry.get_mut().push(name),
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler returns the following error:

```
error[E0532]: expected tuple struct/variant, found struct `VacantEntry`
  --> src/main.rs:26:13
   |
26 |             VacantEntry(entry) => entry.entry(department).or_insert(vec![name]),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ did you mean `VacantEntry { /* fields */ }`?

error[E0532]: expected tuple struct/variant, found struct `OccupiedEntry`
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
27 |             OccupiedEntry(entry) => entry.get_mut().push(name),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ did you mean `OccupiedEntry { /* fields */ }`?
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. What do these errors mean, and what can I do to fix them and get my code to compile?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between an enum variant and the type of that variant. The variants of `Entry` are `Vacant`, and `Occupied`. You need to match against those variants, not their types.

One way to fix your code would be like this:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{Vacant, Occupied};
match employees.entry(department) {
    Vacant(entry) => { entry.insert(vec![name]); },
    Occupied(mut entry) => { entry.get_mut().push(name); },
}
```

But a much simpler solution would to use the return value of `or_insert`, which is a reference to the vector, and push onto it.

```
employees
    .entry(department)
    .or_insert(Vec::new())
    .push(name);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `or_insert_with`, because of https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.212/index.html#or_fun_call

Comment: And I would suggest `or_default()`.